# Looking for shared Qt stylesheets

Tags: css, qt, pyqt

OK, I'm using PyQt4, and need to "decorate" my program.

and I want to use qss, it is simple, and easy to use/change.

But I found there is no such site to share qss files,

and I'm a programmer not a artist, so I won't try to write it myself.

Are there any styles I can pick?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anywhere to share QSS files. Generally any created one will be application-specific so they aren't often shared.

You'll have more luck looking for QStyle plugins, there are a bunch in KDE and elsewhere that look attractive. You can also try using the different Qt styles that are bundled with Qt.